# Can't deallocate memory at the end of the function

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, free

I have created a function to append a node at the front of a linked list in c++. If I don't comment the last line i.e. the delete temp line, the program runs into an infinite loop but if I comment it, everything runs fine. I was hoping to free the memory allocated to the pointer temp to avoid memory leak. Why is it causing a problem?

```
void addFront(Node **head, int item)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();    // Allocating new memory.
    temp->data = item;          //Storing data in the node.
    temp->next = *head;         //Linking temp pointer to head pointer.
    *head = temp;               //Resetting the head pointer as the new first node.
    //delete temp;              //Deallocating memory.
}
```

Comment: `temp` points to the newly inserted node. Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: you are pointing head to the temp memory and then deallocating which causing head to get deallocated so any operation on head should fail or cause unexpected behaviour based on how head is used

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 'new' once, so you only allocated node once. There is no need to "avoid leak" since you never copied the node.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse pointers with the pointee. `delete temp` deletes the object pointed to by `temp`, but that is the node you just inserted in your tree.
You do not need to manually manage the memory of the pointer itself, because it uses automatic storage.

`new Node();` does more than allocating memory. It allocates memory and creates a `Node` by calling its constructor. Instead of two phase construction, members should be initiliazed by calling the constructor.

Slightly modified comments:

```
void addFront(Node **head, int item)
{
    Node *temp = new Node(item,*head); // create new node. temp is a pointer to it
    *head = temp;                      // head points to the new node
    //delete temp;                     // delete the new node ?!?
}
```

There is no memory leak, because now `*head` does point to the newly created node.

This is a memory leak:

```
 void foo() {
     int* x = new int;
 }
```

because after the function returns you have no way to access `x` and have no way to release its memory. While this is not a memory leak:

```
 void bar() {
     int * x;
 }
```

As mentioned above, `x` itself uses automatic storage and its memory is released automatically when the function returns. Colloquially we say: `x` is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it causing a problem?

If the purpose of the function is to add a new node, then it should follow that there would be more nodes after the function than there were before calling the function.

If you create one node, and delete it, then there would be no more nodes after the function than there was before. This contradicts with the described postcodition that there should be more nodes than there was before.

You haven't shown the part of the program where you do this, but presumably you somehow use the list after you've created it. You cannot use nodes that you've already deleted.

---

> If I don't comment the last line i.e. the delete temp line, the program runs into an infinite loop

Deleting the node there is the wrong way to fix the infinite loop that you haven't shown.

---

> I was hoping to free the memory allocated to the pointer temp to avoid memory leak.

You will have to follow the following order of operations:

- Create node
- Use node
- Free node

You cannot do the following. It won't work:

- Create node
- Free node
- Use node (can't do this after freeing the memory)